# Nesting .then() functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Is it bad practice to nest multiple then functions? It seems fairly logical to say "execute this function, and when it's done, execute this one" (and so on) but the code looks horrible.

If it helps I originally had this query in the context of firestore getting user details then getting documents

```
firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
   //If error    
}).then(()=>{   
    firebaseApp.firestore().collection(collectionName).where("associatedID", "==", authID).get().then((snapshot)=>{
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            //Do stuff with data that we've just grabbed
        })
    }).then(()=>{
        //Tell the user in the UI
    });
});
```

Are there alternatives? One that springs to mind is like so

```
var functionOne = () =>{
     console.log("I get called later");
}
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
setTimeout(function() {
    resolve('foo');
  }, 3000);
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
  functionOne();
});
```

But even then it seems like it could get complex after a few .then()'s

Comment: You can return promises in the `.then` block so that you'll only get one level of nesting - https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Comment: ...Or sidestep the issue completely by embracing `async/await` instead of dealing directly with the `Promise` interface. Your code will immediately become very much more readable. If this is (for some reason) not possible, this post should prove useful: https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/how-to-get-out-of-promise-hell-8c20e0ab0513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should chain promises and, also, you can name the functions, which IMHO can improve readibility significantly. Consider something like this

```
const signIn = () => firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

const onSigninError = (err) => // error handling logic here

const getCollection = () => firebaseApp.firestore().collection(collectionName).where("associatedID", "==", authID)
    .get();

const processSnapshot = (snapshot) => snapshot.doc.forEach(// do stuff here

const displayMessage = () => // do stuff here

signIn()
    .catch(onSigninError)
    .then(getCollection)
    .then(processSnapshot)
    .then(displayMessage);
```

Answer (score 2):

Return the Promise from the first outer `.then`, and then use the resolve value in a second outer `.then`, without any nested `.then`s:

```
firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(()=>{   
    return firebaseApp.firestore().collection(collectionName).where("associatedID", "==", authID).get()
  })
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      //Do stuff with data that we've just grabbed
    });
    //Tell the user in the UI
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // handle errors
  });
```

Make sure not to `catch` too early - if there's an error anywhere in the chain, often you'll want to stop normal execution and go directly to the end (eg, tell the user that there was an error).

If you're worried about code readability, consider using `async`/`await` (and transpile down your production code for older browsers):

```
// in an async function:
try {
  await firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  const snapshot = await firebaseApp.firestore().collection(collectionName).where("associatedID", "==", authID).get()
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    //Do stuff with data that we've just grabbed
  });
  //Tell the user in the UI
} catch(error) {
  // handle errors
}
```

Comment: Excellent point about `async`/`await` (and about not having to put "Tell the user in the UI" in a separate `then` handler).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do: If you need access both to the result passed into `then` *and* to the result of a subsequent operation you're doing within the `then` at the same time, nesting is reasonable:

```
doSomething()
.then(result1 => {
    return doSomethingElse()
    .then(result2 => {
        return result1 + result2;
    });
})
.then(combinedResult => {
    // Use `combinedResult`...
})
.catch(/*...*/);
```

often, though, you just need to pass a single value through the chain, by returning the promise from your subsequent operation from the `then` handler:

```
doSomething()
.then(result => {
    return doSomethingElse(result);
})
.then(lastResult => {
    // `lastResult` is the fulfillment value from `doSomethingElse(result)`
})
.catch(/*...*/);
```

Doing that resolves the promise `then` created to the promise returned by `get()` on the query. (To "*resolve* a promise *to* something" means that you've made the promise's settlement depend on the thing you've resolved it to. If you resolve it to another promise, its settlement depends on the settlement of that other promise.)

Looking at your Firebase example, I'd probably do it without nesting:

```
firebaseApp.auth()
.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(() => firebaseApp.firestore().collection(collectionName).where("associatedID", "==", authID).get())
.then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        // Do stuff with data
    });
})
.then(() => {
    // Tell the user in the UI
})
.catch(function(error) {
   // Handle/report error, which may be from `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, your collection query, or an error raised by your code in the `then` handlers above
});
```